# geoDjango on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, gdal, geodjango, geos

I'm using heroku to develop a django backend. I would like to enable geoDjango to use spatial feature with my models. 
I followed all the steps that are describe on the django and heroku docs but I'm still getting an error when I want to run manage.py migrate or other request and command on the server:

```
OSError: /app/.heroku/vendor/lib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did check with bash if it was true and yes there no lib directory in my vendor. I don't know a lot about buildpacks and config on heroku so I don't know where to start to fix this error.
Here is my buildspack:

1. https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
2. heroku/python

And in my .buildpacks I tried to put:

```
https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#e1b845b
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

I also tried different forks that were not able to build at all...

I did put the paths in my settings:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

I'm a bit lost so help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: 
So I tried to downgrade my stack to heroku-16 (it was heroku-18) and it build but when I want to migrate it show me a new error message:

```
OSError: /app/.heroku/vendor/lib: cannot read file data: Is a directory
```

And when I try to follow [this tutorial](https://goodcode.io/articles/django-heroku-gdal-problem/) I can't even build and get this:

```
-----> geos/gdal/proj app detected
   Using geos version: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   Using gdal version: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   Using proj version: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
/app/tmp/buildpacks/3174f4234c5151450fcaba5f50a050126498959c8209a7a6057230bfb29be2eaef3ae0098ab726ef807728f7b4792e31db50a2b89636ae181d9e71b03f2f83c1/bin/compile: line 82: [: too many arguments
/app/tmp/buildpacks/3174f4234c5151450fcaba5f50a050126498959c8209a7a6057230bfb29be2eaef3ae0098ab726ef807728f7b4792e31db50a2b89636ae181d9e71b03f2f83c1/bin/compile: line 88: [: too many arguments
/app/tmp/buildpacks/3174f4234c5151450fcaba5f50a050126498959c8209a7a6057230bfb29be2eaef3ae0098ab726ef807728f7b4792e31db50a2b89636ae181d9e71b03f2f83c1/bin/compile: line 94: [: too many arguments
cp: target '/tmp/build_a7cfd7a56646fe632a93fc752b8ee03d/.heroku/vendor/lib/.' is not a directory
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile geos/gdal/proj app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally managed to find a solution, I had setup two variable in my settings.py as it was said in different tutorial and on the official doc:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

But I don't know why those variable happend to be:

```
/app/.heroku/vendor/lib
```

And that's why it didn't work, so my solution is just to hardcode my paths for heroku:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgeos_c.so' if os.environ.get('ENV') == 'HEROKU' else os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgdal.so' if os.environ.get('ENV') == 'HEROKU' else os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Be careful, you really need to put the "_c" to "libgeos_c.so" otherwise it's not working.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Came here because could not deploy GeoDjango to Heroku with similar error.
Took me some time to find out the way

Since November 2020 you'll need this buildpack: [heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack)

Source with guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1947